# Is it possible to install Oracle 11g server version on Windows 7?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-7

I want to install Oracle 11g Server on my Windows 7 (Non-Server OS) system.
If it is possible, then what steps can I follow for Client and Server installation?

Comment: By *Non-Server OS* do you mean Windows Home Edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to install Oracle 11g server version on Windows 7?

Yes, it is possible.

> what steps can I follow for Client and Server installation?

Follow the installation manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_11.htm

Chapter "Microsoft Windows Installation Guides".

There are separate manuals for 32 and 64-bit systems there, choose the right one depending on a "bitness" of your system.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you just need to follow the linked installation guide closely.  And to that I would draw your attention to the list of supported operating systems under "Software Requirements".  Note that it excludes "home" editions of Windows.  Some people report they have installed on home editions, but it is not supported by Oracle and your mileage may vary.

You could always install VirtualBox (free) then use that to create a vm running Oracle Linux (free) and install Oracle on that.